# How to understand why this does not return the minimum value?

Tags: java

Please help to understand why, in the following, I didn't get output of minimum value in array. Using scanner for input value, the program should output also the minimum number.

** without using `.sort`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int[] list;
    list = new int[10000];
    int sum = 0;
    double avr = 0;
    int min = list [0];
    int max = list [0];
    int x = 0;
    int value;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Add number " + (x + 1) + ": ");
    value = input.nextInt();

    while (x <= list.length && (value != -1 || x == 0)) {
        list[x] = value;
        x++;
        System.out.print("Add number " + (x + 1) + ": ");
        value = input.nextInt();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        sum += list[i];
        avr = sum / x;

        if(list[i] > max)
            max = list[i]; 

        if( list[i] < min )
            min = list[i];

    }


    System.out.println("The sum of all values are: " + sum);
    System.out.println("The average value of the numbers are: " + avr);
    System.out.println("The maximum value of the numbers are: " + max);
    System.out.println("The minimum value of the numbers are: " + min);


}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [tour], go through the [help], read [ask] and put some effort in your question if you want us to put some effort as well in the answer(s) (i.e. spell the words correctly (and completely), indent your code, describe the problem as well as you can)

Comment: Please take the time to read your own question and make it easier to read & understand!

Comment: The question's not clear - please read [ask].

Comment: Note that you don't need the `list` array to calculate these values. You just need the `min`, `max`, `sum` and `x` variables, and update them each time you read another number.

Comment: Thank you i'm just a begginer in java and here

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest two improvements at the bare minimum.

1. Initialize your `min` to the first `value`. Right now you have min initialized to 0 and user never enters any number smaller than 0. That's why you keep getting 0 for min.
2. Don't run your loops 1000 times. Run it as many times as there are non zero elements.

See the following working snippet:

```
 int[] list;
        list = new int[10000];
        int sum = 0;
        double avr = 0;
        int min = list [0];
        int max = list [0];
        int x = 0;
        int value;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Add number " + (x + 1) + ": ");
        value = input.nextInt();
        min = value;
        while (x <= list.length && (value != -1 || x == 0)) {
            list[x] = value;
            x++;
            System.out.print("Add number " + (x + 1) + ": ");
            value = input.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length && list[i] !=0; i++) {
            sum += list[i];
            avr = sum / x;

            if(list[i] > max)
                max = list[i]; 

            if( list[i] < min )
                min = list[i];

        }


        System.out.println("The sum of all values are: " + sum);
        System.out.println("The average value of the numbers are: " + avr);
        System.out.println("The maximum value of the numbers are: " + max);
        System.out.println("The minimum value of the numbers are: " + min);
```

Comment: There are other bugs in here that you've not fixed.

Comment: @AndyTurner, I don't intend to. I am just trying to give OP a bare minimum answer on why he is getting 0 for his min.

Comment: Just a side note: The above "working snippet" will produce a ***ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException*** IF a User actually does enter the ten thousandth value. :)  `x <= list.length`

Comment: @DevilsHnd, go ahead and post your own answer making sure it is accurate on every front. My intention is to solve the problem highlighted by the OP, not every problem that he has not even asked for help on.

Comment: Thank you very much